# How to handle imbalance in input variables?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, class-imbalance, imbalanced-data

Currently working on a finance dataset which has more than 20 input variables with high imbalance.

[Apparently, the target variable is also imbalanced (for this I am currently considering to handle it using class_weights parameter of scikit-learn)]

Comment: What is the type of your variables? Can you provide a concrete example of an imbalance of such variables?

Comment: Why do anything for either the inputs or the target?

Comment: @Eduard all of them are categorical.

Comment: @Dave wouldn't you treat class imbalance differently?

Comment: Imbalance of what, and why is it a problem? // Statistics sees minimal problem with target imbalance, yet apparent myths persist. Please refer to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) question for details on why and [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any) for additional links.